# How to use boyer_moore_search to search char * string in memory?

Tags: c++, boost

```
char * pStart = ...;
char * pLast = ...;
std::string pattern("wn3901s");

std::string::const_iterator it = boost::algorithm::boyer_moore_search<>(  
    ???, 
    ???,  
    pattern.begin(),  
    pattern.end()
);
```

I am trying to search a big `char*` string in memory, `pStart` points to its first charactor address; `pLast` points to the last.

However, I don't want to convert the `char*` string into `std::string`, because in that case the memory is copied and that is what I want to avoid.

Now I have the problem to pass the first 2 parameters for `boyer_moore_search` method, which accepts `const_iterator` there.

Should I add a new inherited class from `const_iterator` to emulate the `char*` string?
Could there be any example?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `char *` as iterator

```
char *iterator_ = boost::algorithm::boyer_moore_search(pStart, pLast, pattern.begin(), pattern.end());
```

> An iterator is any object that, pointing to some element in a range of
>   elements (such as an array or a container), has the ability to iterate
>   through the elements of that range using a set of operators (with at
>   least the increment (++) and dereference (*) operators).
>
> The most obvious form of iterator is a pointer.
>
> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, as sliser has just pointed out...

```
#include<boost/algorithm/searching/boyer_moore.hpp>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>

using boost::algorithm::boyer_moore_search;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  const char * text_start = "This is the string in which we will search for the pattern.";
  const char * text_end = text_start + strlen(text_start);
  const char * pattern_start = "search";
  const char * pattern_end = pattern_start + strlen(pattern_start);

  const char * found = boyer_moore_search(text_start, text_end, pattern_start, pattern_end);

  printf("%s", found);

  return 0;
}
```